# WPF can we swap panels (DockPanel, StackPanel)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, stackpanel, dockpanel

I want to create two diffent types of DockPanels. If the user clicks on one link, it loads DockPanel #1 otherwise it loads #2.

Can we dynamically swap them? I'm new to WPF. In REALBasic, I'd use GroupPanels and I'd swap them if needed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "swap" and "load"?  It certainly sounds possible, but it's difficult to give you a good answer without knowing a little more about your design.  That being said, it sounds like a good candidate for an MVVM app.

Comment: never really understood MVVM. Tried to but can't grasp the concept of MVVM. (MVC i know)

Comment: This is really an aside and kind of broad, but MVVM is "very" similar to MVC.  The Models are the same in each, and the Views are used to display the data.  The difference is that last part - in MVVM, the View talks exclusively to the ViewModel, and the VM does all the talking to the Model (as well as handle all the commands).  That's admittedly an overly generalized explanation, but it (hopefully) gives you another piece to the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can dynamicly create controls and fill their content with other controls. Or u can just place both types and hide one u dont want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Josh Smith's MVVM Article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).  Josh is considered by many to be The MVVM Guru, and this article does a good job at explaining the basics.

With that in mind, I would probably do your app as an MVVM application.

The Model would "just" be your data model (much like in MVC).

Next there would be a View for each of your panels.  Each View could either be set up as a DataTemplate (like in the article), or as a UserControl (as I've done and seen done many other places as well).  Doing so makes it modular, and easier to expand, maintain, etc.

Your MainWindow is really also considered a View, onto which you place other Views.

All of the Views will be controlled by one or more ViewModel classes.  How many you have depends on your design.  Generally, if there is distinct functionality, you will have a more-or-less one-to-one relationship between a View and a ViewModel (although you can certainly share multiple Views with a single ViewModel).  There will also generally be a single "Main ViewModel" class to hold everything together.

In general terms given the general description of your problem, it is likely that your ViewModel will contain a Command (or Commands), handled when your user chooses a link.  This Command will likely set some property, which will control which View gets shown (usually via Binding).

Sorry I can't get more detailed than this, but if I did I'd need to know more about your design, and I'd have to write a lot more stuff, which isn't really appropriate in this forum.